# TDI_RECEIVE request handling

Tags: tcp, kernel, driver

I'm writing simple TDI filter driver (well, I remember that it's year 2013 now )))). I need to inspect first chunk of HTTP reply. So I intercept TDI_RECEIVE request, setup my completion routine and forward IRP to next driver. In completion routine I'd like to inspect returned chunk.

Code is following:

```
case TDI_RECEIVE:{
            PVOID buf = MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe(Irp->MdlAddress,HighPagePriority);
            ULONG size = MmGetMdlByteCount(Irp->MdlAddress);

            IoCopyCurrentIrpStackLocationToNext(Irp);
            ntStatus = IoSetCompletionRoutineEx(MntrDevice,Irp,IoCompletion, NULL,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE);
            break;
............................................................................
 ntStatus = IoCallDriver ( NextDevice , Irp );
 return ntStatus ;
```

Completion routine:

```
PVOID buf = MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe(irp->MdlAddress,HighPagePriority);
int size = Irp->IoStatus.Information;
```

It's very strange, but there is only one TDI_RECEIVE request with one MD about 3K, and corresponding completed IRP contains LAST chunk of the WEB-pager (i.e. no HTTP response, no page beginning). And I don't see any other recv/read requests.

Any suggestion where they are hiding (actually I need only first chunk of first HTTP response per TCP session)?

Answer (score 0):

You need make hook on set TDI_EVENT_CHAINED_RECEIVE callback (actually there are more callbacks, but this one works). In this callback you can analyze received data and than call original callback.